# Splitting char array into chunks quickly c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there a faster/ more efficient way to split a char array into chunks (say 21 chars/ array) other than looping over the whole array?

This is my attempt right now

```
const char* arr = line.c_str();
char smallArr[(int)ceil((double)strlen(arr)/(double)21)][21];
int arrSisze[(int)ceil((double)strlen(arr)/(double)21)][1];
int m=0;int n=0;
for (int i=0; i<strlen(arr); i++) {
    smallArr[m][i]=arr[i];
    arrSisze[m][0]=(i+1)-n;
    if ((i-n)==19) {
        m++;
        n+=20;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `double` is even involved **at all?** This indicates some **very low-quality code.** Not to mention the dupe call to `strlen()`... And no, you can't have array operations better than `O(n)`, you have to walk through the array. Also, you forget to NUL-terminate the substrings. And don't reinvent the wheel, use the standard library instead of rolling your own `strcpy()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Whilst I agree it was probably a mistake, recording the sizes of the strings could indicate he didn't need NUL-terminated strings.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, pointer arithmetic and `memcpy`. However, seeing as you're using C++, let's stick to `std::string`s and assume they do a `memcpy` for us.

```
std::vector<std::string> output;
output.reserve(line.length() / 21 + (line.length() % 21) ? 1 : 0);

auto i = line.begin(), j = i + 21;
for(; line.end() - j > 21; i = j, j+= 21)
{
    output.emplace(i, j)
}

if(j != line.end())
{
    output.emplace(j, line.end());
}
```

So, what is going on here? For our purpose, it is good enough to think of a `std::string` as a `char` array and a `length` variable.

First, we reserve enough space for our output. You did this too.

Next, we define 2 variables `i` and `j`. `i` represents the beginning of the current substring and `j` the one-past-the-end iterator. Iterators here can be thought of as pointers into the internal structure of the `string`'s `char` array - they may even be `char*`s!

We then iterate over the original string a line at a time. `emplace` just constructs a new element of a `vector` in the correct place. The call is equivalent to `output.push_back(std::string(i, j))` and is only available in C++11.

To finish, we check whether there is another whole chunk using `line.end() - j > 21`; `line.end()` is the one-past-the-end iterator for the `char` array - it points at the `NUL` character (if there is one). If there is not a whole chunk, we check for a partial chunk using `j != line.end()`.

Comment: He may not be familiar with iterators - you may want to explain what's going on here.

Answer (score 3):

**1) Using memcpy**

```
char myname[] = "hello";
char dest[20] = {0};    
/* using memcpy to copy string: */
 memcpy ( dest, myname, 5);
```

**2) using strncpy**

```
char str1[]= "To be or not to be";
char str2[40];

strncpy ( str2, str1, sizeof(str2) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-optimize the standard library.

- If you have a std::string, just use it.
- Don't use floating point for integer calculations: just use integer arthmetic porperly
- the problem complexity is O(1). No other solution will cover it with less of one string walk span, and related copies
- Use C++ properly, and **forget C**.

=

```
std::vector<std::string> chunks;
chunks.resize(21);
size_t chunksize = line.size()/21+1;
for(size_t i=0,j=0; i<line.size(); i+=chunksize, ++j)
{  chunks[j] = line.substr(i,chunksize); }
```

Note that `sting::size` takes N^0, while `strlen` takes N^1 complexity (it has a loop inside).

In this code, my loop is 21^1 on chunks and substr is (N/21)^1 each chunk content, giving N^1 on the whole length.

There is no need to track string length and null terminate the strings. All is handled by std::string class.

Comment: -1 all your big-Os are off; it should read, for example, "`std::string::size` is O(1), while `strlen` is O(N), where `N` is the length of the string itself`. Furthermore, your algorithm doesn't do what the OP asked for.

Comment: Duh! I was meaning N^0, N^1 etc. but I didn't find a way to represent it. Big O is just an incidentally similar notation. Being confusingm better to change it properly.

Comment: ...About the algorithm: the request is "split a line into smaller chunks". It has not necessarily to be the same as the OP attempt.